# Skip to next div slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slideshow with some images. I change between divs that contain images with next and prev keys (every div contain an image). I want to be able to hide one of these picture. Not just hide it, but skipping to next div. The example is from w3school I want to be able to **skip** the images that have a specific class, not just hide them. Because when I tried to make display to none, this hided the image but the div is still showing.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/220" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

 
<div class="dontview" style="display:none">
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/212" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dontview" style="display:none">
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/241" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/244" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it better to write

```
<div class="mySlides fade dontview">
```

instead of

```
<div class="dontview" style="display:none">
<div class="mySlides fade">
```

then to skip element that has class `dontview` do

```
if (slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.contains("dontview")) {
    return showSlides(slideIndex += 1)
}
```

demo

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides"),
  dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");

let slideIndex = 0;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function isSkip(n) {
  return slides[slideIndex + n].classList.contains("dontview");
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    if (slideIndex == slides.length - 1)
      return showSlides(slideIndex = 0)
    if (isSkip(1)) {
      slideIndex += 1
      return plusSlides(1)
    }
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    if (slideIndex == 0)
      return showSlides(slideIndex = slides.length - 1)
    if (isSkip(-1)) {
      slideIndex -= 1
      return plusSlides(-1)
    }
  }

  slideIndex += n
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = slideIndex == i ? "block" : "none";
    dots[i].className = slideIndex == i ? "dot active" : "dot";
  }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}
body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides{display:none}
img{vertical-align:middle}
.slideshow-container{max-width:200px;position:relative;margin:auto}
.prev,.next{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:50%;width:auto;padding:16px;margin-top:-22px;color:#fff;font-weight:700;font-size:18px;transition:.6s ease;border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;user-select:none}
.next{right:0;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px}
.prev:hover,.next:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
.text{color:#f2f2f2;font-size:15px;padding:8px 12px;position:absolute;bottom:8px;width:100%;text-align:center}
.numbertext{color:#f2f2f2;font-size:12px;padding:8px 12px;position:absolute;top:0}
.dot{cursor:pointer;height:15px;width:15px;margin:0 2px;background-color:#bbb;border-radius:50%;display:inline-block;transition:background-color .6s ease}
.active,.dot:hover{background-color:#717171}
.fade{animation-name:fade;animation-duration:1.5s}
@keyframes fade {from{opacity:.4}to{opacity:1}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {.prev,.next,.text{font-size:11px}}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=1" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade dontview">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=2" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000/FFFFFF/?text=3" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade dontview">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=4" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption four</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/006600/FFFFFF/?text=5" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption five</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, this is exactly what I need.
<3 <3

Comment: There is just one problem.
When I press prev, it stops when it finds a hidden div.
It working when you move to next throught all divs (1 to 4 to 5), but when you try the opposite side it stops working(from 4 to 1).
I have tried to edit it but still nt working, sorry for late checking.
I just notised it.

Comment: I forgot about the prev button but it fixed now, see updated code

Comment: Thank you my friend, you are amazing :) :)

Comment: Is it possible to have a filter for these slides.
lets think that there are different divs with 4 types of colors.
__3 divs are blue
__4 divs are green
__2 divs are yellow
__5 divs are black

__and 4 filter buttons, if I press black then I could choose from the black divs (I won't be able to see the other divs with other colors)